# Update selected values in a jsonb column containing a array

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Table `faults` contains column `recacc` (jsonb) which contains an array of json objects. Each of them contains a field `action`. If the value for `action` is `abc`, I want to change it to `cba`. Changes to be applied to all rows.

```
[
  {
    "action": "abc",
    "created": 1128154425441
  },
  {
    "action": "lmn",
    "created": 1228154425441
  },
  {
    "action": "xyz",
    "created": 1328154425441
  }
]
```

The following doesn't work, probably because of the data being in array format

```
update faults 
  set recacc = jsonb_set(recacc,'{action}', to_jsonb('cbe'::TEXT),false) 
where recacc ->> 'action' = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but you may first get the elements of jsonb using `jsonb_array_elements`, replace it and then reconstruct the json using `array_agg` and `array_to_json`.

```
UPDATE faults SET recacc = new_recacc::jsonb
FROM 
 (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(s)) as new_recacc 
 FROM
   (  SELECT 
         replace(c->>'action','abc','cba') , --this to change the value
          c->>'created' FROM faults f
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(f.recacc)  as c
   )  as s (action,created)
) m;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6f65d24bb63caf38653edbd559ed3daf)

Comment: I can confirm that the Demo link shows that the solution works - thanks